# Wordpress: site moved to Open Litespeed internal links throw 404 error

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, litespeed

I received a backed up wordpress site. I tried to deploy it on an `Open Litespeed Webserver`. But when I visit internal links I receive 404 error.

I tried flushing the permalinks, changed the .htaccess to

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/index\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Based on this [solution](https://www.basezap.com/solved-404-error-on-wordpress-website-on-litespeed-webserver/)

I restarted the server but with no luck. I cannot find a way to make it work.

In LiteSpeed I have these settings also:

> Rewrite Control -> Enable Rewrite : Yes
>   Rewrite Rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  ^NameOfBadRobot
RewriteRule ^/nospider/         -   [F]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That worked for me:

[migration instructions (step 1)](https://openlitespeed.org/kb/migrate-apache-rewrite-rules-to-openlitespeed/)

Comment: It would be useful to know exactly "what" worked in this case, rather than linking to a page that contains a lot of varied information?! In short, if you are moving between `.htaccess` on both platforms (Apache vs LiteSpeed) then you wouldn't necessarily need to change the default WordPress directives. The guide you link to is primarily for migrating between `.htaccess` and server config directives.